# maximized qmainwindow gets bigger then screen

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmainwindow, qlayout

I have QMainWindow with widgets, all the widgets have layout.
But, when I play with the maximize and minimize QMainWindow buttons, I get the QMainWindow bigger then the screen size.

Is there any property / flag that disable this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: could you give a simple example with that issue? Tried by myself and everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my widget was not set as CentralWidget of the Qt mainwindow.

That solved my issue, thanks anyway.